# How to adjust UITextView and scrollview dynamically based on data

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

In my project i have to adjust UItextview and UIScrollView dynamically based on data i am trying so much but perfect result is not coming please help me some one.

See my code for growing textview based on data and i don't know how to grow UIScrollView based on data please somebody help me.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of textview frame as

```
CGRect frame = textView.frame;
frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
textView.frame=frame;
```

or you can try below code.

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [textView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
   return size.height;
}
```

or even You can try below code.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: textView.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle };

    CGRect size = [textToMeasure boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame), MAXFLOAT)
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:attributes
                                              context:nil];
```

Comment: i want growing textview1 when user edits textview1 and also have to change remaining scrollview and textview2 frames thats what my question

Comment: what ur scrollview & textview 2 contains ?